# Why does Emacs not enter the debugger when popping a cons twice?

Tags: debugging, error-handling

I wrote some LISP code that was wrong because I was trying to `pop` a `cons` twice:

```
(let ((pair '("a" . "b")))
  (let* ((a (pop pair))
     (b (pop pair)))
    b))
```

Evaluating this in the `*scratch*` buffer showed `setq: Wrong type argument: listp, "b"` in the mini-buffer. I realized that `pop` requires a list and thus fails the second time; instead, `car` and `cdr` work.

I have `Enter Debugger on Error` enabled. Why doesn't Emacs enter the debugger to show an approximate location of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

`*scratch*`:

```
(let ((pair '("a" . "b")))
  (let* ((a (pop pair))
     (b (pop pair)))
    b))
```

<kbd>C-j</kbd>

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp "b")
  cdr("b")
  (setq pair (cdr pair))
  (prog1 pair (setq pair (cdr pair)))
  (car-safe (prog1 pair (setq pair (cdr pair))))
  (let* ((a (car-safe (prog1 pair (setq pair (cdr pair))))) (b (car-safe (prog1 pair (setq pair (cdr pair)))))) b)
  (let ((pair (quote ("a" . "b")))) (let* ((a (car-safe (prog1 pair (setq pair (cdr pair))))) (b (car-safe (prog1 pair (setq pair (cdr pair)))))) b))
  eval((let ((pair (quote ("a" . "b")))) (let* ((a (car-safe (prog1 pair (setq pair ...)))) (b (car-safe (prog1 pair (setq pair ...))))) b)) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-print-last-sexp)
```

---

Chances are that the debugger is *already* active.  Look for a `*Backtrace*` buffer, and check for the square brackets in the mode line indicating a recursive edit.

Just visit the `*Backtrace*` buffer and quit that debug session, and then trigger your new error again.

You could alternatively <kbd>C-M-c</kbd> to `exit-recursive-edit`, or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `top-level` to exit *all* recursive edits.  For details read <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Recursive Edit`